# Magick++ API: Get PDF page count?

Tags: c++, pdf, imagemagick, magick++

I'm struggling to write a function to get the number of pages from a PDF without using external/additional (ie, other-than-Magick++) libraries for this purpose -- yet, when I execute something like this:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
    InitializeMagick(*argv);

    Image master; 
    master.ping("a-66-page-pdf.pdf[999999]");

    return 0;
}
```

(Where *[999999]* refers to the page requested)

It dumps an error like this:

```
Requested FirstPage is greater than the number of pages in the file: 66
   No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorDelegate'
  what():  Magick: Postscript delegate failed (a-66-page-pdf.pdf) reported by coders/pdf.c:434 (ReadPDFImage)
Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

ie, **It knows that the pdf has *66* pages** -- yet I can't figure out how to get that information from it except by making it crash like this?

Is there a way?

Comment: Why not handle the exception?  Also, `coders/pdf.c:434` is the line that determines the number of pages -- it appears right in the exception message.

Comment: Looking for coders/pdf.c was the first thing that I tried, but there's no file called "pdf.c" anywhere on my system (I assume it's somewhere in the original Magick++ source, and I'll keep looking. Somehow I feel like this problem should be more trivial than it feels so far)

Comment: Whatever is responsible for parsing the PDF knows the page count.  There is no need to iteratively go through the PDF to get the page count *if* the PDF is parsed properly for the dictionaries, objects, etc.  (Is it Magick++, or an add-on library that Magick++ uses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can come up with, if anyone's facing the same problem working with ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick, without including an *entire extra library* for this *one function* (**PoDoFo**, which is unstable, can do this, and **poppler** can also do it) is to use this based on the code written in the question:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <cstring>

using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    
    try {

        Image master;
    
        char cmd[4096] = {""};
        strcat(cmd, argv[1]);
        strcat(cmd, "[99999999999]");
        master.ping(cmd);
    
    } catch( Exception &error_ )
    {
        // do nothing
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
./compiled-program any-given-pdf.pdf 2>/dev/null | grep file: | awk {'print $13'}
```

Maybe with popen() etc. Maybe you could redirect stdout to a string, I haven't tried yet.

It's janky, it feels like a hack, but it's a ***hell of a lot faster*** (I mean almost infinitely faster) than trying to load a list/vector/array with ping() or readImages() and count the size of the list.

It's endlessly frustrating that Magick++ offers no accessible method to retrieve a PDF's page count, and yet evidently not only **is capable** of getting a page count, but **does so** every time an image is pinged.

If you're alright with including an **entire library** for just one function, *poppler* and *PoDoFo* can do this.

Obviously this will fail on a 100-billion page PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ImageMagick-7, use the STL method.

```cpp
std::list<Magick::Image> master;
Magick::pingImages(&master, "a-66-page-pdf.pdf");
std::cout << master.size() << std::endl;
```

The `pingImages` method is not available with ImageMagick-6, so you'll need to read all the images.

```cpp
Magick::ReadOptions opts;
// Set dpi & depth, if needed
// opts.depth(8);
// opts.density(72);
std::list<Magick::Image> master;
Magick::readImages(&master, "a-66-page-pdf.pdf", opts);
std::cout << master.size() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize a counter and create that string with counter as the index. As long as you increment the counter in a while loop with your code inside a try-catch block, when the above exception is thown, your counter would indicate the number of pages.

Comment: If you're going to do things that way, might as well do a binary search for the value.  What if the PDF file has thousands of pages?

Comment: I don't know how this library works, but I think that ping is a method that is not really heavy. So, for thousands of pages, as you say, with a binary search would work perfectly fine. For a faster method than that, probably it exists a method in the library for this becsuse the exception shows the number of pages in that pdf.

Comment: It's a solid idea, @apopa, but it does take quite a bit of time (especially for very large PDFs)

I also tried doing a binary search for the /Count value (specified standard in the PDF format), but something like 25% of PDFs don't fully comply with this standard, and that binary search fails on those

Comment: You could try setting the density very low (say 8) on the PDF before scanning it - that will make rasterisation much faster.

Comment: I read a little bit documentation of this library and I found a method called readImages. You can try to do this: std::list<Image> pages; readImages(&pages, path+filename); The number of pages is then pages.size().

Comment: To get the total number of pages in the PDF requires a lookup in the `/Pages` entry in the `/Catalog` object, from what I remember.  Then that points you to the element where the page count is stored.  The problem is that the PDF needs to be parsed, since it is hierarchical in nature -- that's what the PDF's libraries are there for, because this work is not trivial in nature.